# How do I show only the level in monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, software-engineering

[image]

How do I remove the blue background shown here
So that only the level is visible without making the sprites/map larger or the window smaller?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you mean by 'remove' if you don't want to upscale the level nor resize the window?

Comment: I wanted to make the tilemap fill up the entire window

Comment: You make the map bigger?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to see in the area that's currently blue? Or even better, use a paint tool to make a quick mock-up of what the window should look like, and show us?

Comment: I've closed this question because it's lacking details. Please edit the question by trying to answer all the questions you've received in the comments so we can reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to dynamically scale the camera so you can only see the map. This can be done by passing a different projection matrix to the `SpriteBatch`:

```
var graphics = /* your GraphicsDeviceManager */;
var width = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
var height = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;

var windowSize = new Vector2(width, height);
var gameSize = new Vector2(someWidth, someHeight); // e.g. your mapWidth and mapHeight
var matrix = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(windowSize / gameSize, 1));

spriteBatch.Begin(
    // All of these need to be here :(
    SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
    samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp,
    effect: null,
    blendState: null,
    rasterizerState: null,
    depthStencilState: null,
    // THIS!
    transformationMatrix: matrix,
);
// draw stuff
spriteBatch.End();
```

You can also multiply matrices to combine their effects:

```
// Just to show you the types :) gotta find the values yourself!
int windowWidth;
int windowHeight;
Vector2 position;
Vector2 windowSize = new Vector2(windowWidth, windowHeight);
Vector2 worldSize;

var translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-position, 0));
var scale = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(windowSize / worldSize * Zoom, 1));
var centerTranslation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 0);
var view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up)

// use matrix with SpriteBatch like my previous example
var matrix = translation * scale * centerTranslation * view;
```

The above code would scale the camera and center it on `position`.

Comment: I am under the impression that it's not what they want when they say "that only the level is visible _without making the sprites/map larger_". The lack of feedback from the OP makes it hard to know exactly what they're after.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I'm pretty sure they mean they don't want to make the actual `.png` files or whatever bigger :) That's what I base my answer on anyways haha.

Comment: That's probably the case, let's wait and see what they come up with!

Comment: Finally someone did understand what I was trying to say.Yeah sorry I was actually having too much trouble in explaining what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The blue background technically is 'nothing', but it's blue by default. I assume that's so it works better for sprites with black outlines.

If you want to change the blue color to black, it's color is initialised in the `Draw()` method of game1. Either removing that color, or changing it to black will give you the black background.

Otherwise, you'll need to resize/set the window's width/height if you only want the level to be visible.

Comment: I wanted to make the tilemap fill up the entire window.But I am actually finding this quite difficult to explain

Comment: Yet in the question you asked that you want to remove the background without making the sprites/map larger. Do you want to fill the whole background area with rocks?

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely want is that instead of iterating over the map to render it, you iterate over the viewport (sorta) which slides over your map.

Pad that out by a few tiles so that you can have smooth scrolling.

Keep track of the viewport position (you can pin that to your character, but the important part is that it is specifically the viewport you track and not something that mostly, but not always corresponds, like your character's X/Y).

Based on the viewport position, render tiles, however big your viewport is, offset by its position. For example, if your viewport's top left corner is at the top left corner of the map like in your screenshot, you then (probably with a for loop with X and Y) render all tiles starting from map's 0,0 and to the coordinates corresponding to the far right and bottom of your screen. For every tile you check if it's in the map first - if it is, you render whatever the tile is, otherwise (outside of bounds) - you render a border tile (like rocks or trees or water or whatever). Pokémon games used this technique and their border tile was actually made out of 2x2 regular ones to allow for tall trees and such - you can emulate this by keeping track whether you are drawing an odd or even row/column.